# Riemann integrability of a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with exactly 3 points of discontinuity and specific slopes

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

A function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

1. has exactly $3$ points of discontinuity
2. is strictly increasing on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and strictly decreasing on $(\frac{1}{2},1]$.
3. $f$ is Riemann integrable

Is it possible to find a function that has 1. and 2. but isnt Riemann integrable?

Comment: @Neutronic: Hint: Do those conditions imply $f$ is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 &\mbox{if } x=0 \\
x &\mbox{if } x \in (0,\frac{1}{4}] \\
x+1 &\mbox{if } x \in (\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}] \\ 
\frac{1}{x-0,5} & \mbox{if } x\in (\frac{1}{2},1] \end{cases}$$

The Lebesgue’s Criterion for integrability tells us that a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if $f$ is bounded and is almost everyone continuous.

$f$ fullfils condition $1$ and $2$ but $f$ is not bounded hence it is not Riemann-integrable.